# The more precisely we want to locate a particle in space, the more energy we will need to expend

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, fourier-transform, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, elementary-particles

The more precisely we want to locate a particle in space, the more energy we will need to expend. does this statement have a mathematical formulation? When studying quantum mechanics, I often found this statement in textbooks where examples of the uncertainty relation are given: the Heisenberg microscope, when estimating the size of the hydrogen atom using uncertainty principle, Feynman addressed this statement in his lectures. Also, in the question of the applicability of the concept of trajectory to a particle, one of the main criteria is the wavelength. for example, in plasma, we can talk about the trajectory with a high degree of accuracy, since the wavelength is quite short due to the high temperature. High energy low uncertainty in the trajectory.
This confuses me, because with a formal approach at a certain wavelength, that is, at a certain momentum, we cannot talk about the trajectory of a particle at all. only by summing up a certain range of waves, we can talk about the localization of the particle, ideally, taking a certain integral (Fourier integral) over the entire spectrum of waves, we will get a wave packet well localized in space. but what surprises me most is that both approaches produce the right results. So which approach is the right one?

Comment: The higher the energy of probe particles in high-energy physics, the shorter the relevant Compton wavelength probing the shorter distances; however, short distance probing does not "locate" particles in space, anymore, but creates fireballs of new particles: the process has transitioned into relativistic QFT.

Comment: I would like to see a mathematical expression for this statement

Answer (score 0):

Peter Woit furnishes the math in the introductory chapters of his book, *Not Even Wrong*. The general outline of his argument is as follows:

Physicists sometimes use *natural units* (in which, for example, the speed of light is defined to numerically equal one) to make certain equations easier to set up and solve.

When cast in this form, energy has the units of 1/(distance).  This naturally associates high energies with short distances.